# Azure Media services in Austria

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am working on a Media services solution for Austria location. Please point me to link mentioning that MS has a data center in Austria for Media Services. If not which nearest data center i should use services from?

Comment: Please put in a little effort before asking. If you had searched for `Azure Service Availability by Region`, you would have been redirected to this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/global-infrastructure/services/?products=media-services&regions=all

Comment: While that is true, you could easily have done a search for Azure Global Regions, that would still not have answered your specific question about "where is Media Services" deployed. 

At this time I would recommend West Europe (Amsterdam), France, or Germany (a bit pricier).   We are not deployed into the Swiss region yet.

Comment: Better link here which shows Regions by Product (filtered to Media Services) - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?products=media-services&regions=all

Comment: StackOverflow != Google Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here please - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?products=media-services&regions=all

Recommend West Europe, France, or Germany right now.  Not yet in Austria, but there is a Swiss region coming online in the future.